# Unable to retrieve details for the JSON value subsection using Cosmos DB SQL

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a JSON data field that I am trying to process using the Cosmos DB SQL.

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "id": "consultationservice||8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f",
    "value": {
        "Id": "8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Info",
        "proposedMeetingTimes": [
            "2019-01-06T17:16:40",
            "2019-01-06T17:16:40",
            "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
        ],
        "proposedMeetingTime": "2019-01-06T17:16:40",
        "SomeInnerData": [
            {
                "Id": "25c52709-4ef6-4045-a623-5eca3957a532",
                "Email": [
                    "email@email.com",
                    "email1@email.com",
                    "email2@email.com"
                ],
                "connectionInformation": "The best connection",
                "sentOn": "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
            }
        ]
    },
    "partitionKey": "UserAvailability",
    "_rid": "8BMWALYVDbIHAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/8BMWAA==/colls/8BMWALYVDbI=/docs/8BMWALYVDbIHAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-169d-6f5b4f8201d7\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1615484346
}
```

I am able to retrieve any data inside the VALUE section using this format

```
SELECT UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData
FROM UserAvailability
WHERE UserAvailability["value"].Id = '8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f'
```

or

```
SELECT UserAvailability["value"].Email
FROM UserAvailability
WHERE UserAvailability["value"].Id = '8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f'
```

However, no matter what I try to do, I can't retrieve any data inside the SomeInnerData (such as Id, Email, connectionInformation, sentOn) section. Please assist

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SomeInnerData`  is an array, you can't retrieve data by `UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData.Id`.

If you only have one item in this array, you can try this:

```
SELECT UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData[0].Id,UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData[0].Email,UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData[0].connectionInformation,UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData[0].sentOn
FROM UserAvailability
JOIN SID IN UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData
WHERE UserAvailability["value"].Id = '8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f'
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "25c52709-4ef6-4045-a623-5eca3957a532",
        "Email": [
            "email@email.com",
            "email1@email.com",
            "email2@email.com"
        ],
        "connectionInformation": "The best connection",
        "sentOn": "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
    }
]
```

If you have many items, you should use [JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join). Join will result in a complete cross product of the sets participating in the join.

```
SELECT UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData,SID.Id,SID.Email,SID.connectionInformation,SID.sentOn
FROM UserAvailability
JOIN SID IN UserAvailability["value"].SomeInnerData
WHERE UserAvailability["value"].Id = '8acd52b4-f4c3-4124-b1c3-89bc57a25f4f'
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "SomeInnerData": [
            {
                "Id": "25c52709-4ef6-4045-a623-5eca3957a532",
                "Email": [
                    "email@email.com",
                    "email1@email.com",
                    "email2@email.com"
                ],
                "connectionInformation": "The best connection",
                "sentOn": "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
            }
        ],
        "Id": "25c52709-4ef6-4045-a623-5eca3957a532",
        "Email": [
            "email@email.com",
            "email1@email.com",
            "email2@email.com"
        ],
        "connectionInformation": "The best connection",
        "sentOn": "2019-01-06T17:16:40"
    }
]
```